# TIdHTTP, TIdCookingManager - programmatically accept cookies from Google Finance

Tags: delphi, cookies, indy

Delphi XE7, Indy 10.6.0.5169

I am creating the components like this:

```
FHTTP                    := TIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
FHTTP.Request.Connection := 'close';
FHTTP.IOHandler          := CreateSSLIOHandler;
FHTTP.ConnectTimeout     := 0;
FHTTP.ReadTimeout        := 0;
FCookieManager           := TIdCookieManager.Create;
FHTTP.CookieManager      := FCookieManager;`
```

Then I am trying to query Google Finance page, but the response always contains the Accept Cookies page:

```
FExchange := 'NASDAQ';
vUrl := 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/' + FTicker + ':' + FExchange + '?hl=en';
vSL := TStringList.Create;
try
  try
    FHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
    FHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    vSL.Text := FHTTP.Get(vURL);
.......
```

How do I programmatically accept cookies and download the actual quote page?

**UPDATE:**

Now I added an `OnNewCookie` handler and I see the following names/texts being added. The handler sets `VAccept` to TRUE, but that does not help.

```
SOCS
SOCS=CAAaBgiArsumBg;
Path=/;
Domain=google.com;
Secure;
Max-Age=34127999;
Expires=Sat, 07-Sep-2024 09:42:50 GMT

__Secure-ENID
__Secure-ENID=13.SE=ioKJcdGZB8gJCJYvq5OUqdA3WEcFO-rRgj7elSr3t7gPbrLKhtYqo7eUw3Cwp-Q3L8ODN_NVpJXSqBIePZNmGBfxXRvDmf0zkqrHu5uRZifeaB6SSfN4P2P7LzMk_Z4h_opf9GfsOhF9kVrIE5lFHUuLXoTECeXMlSPDfJ0Txi4;
Path=/;
Domain=google.com;
Secure;
HttpOnly;
Max-Age=34186697;
Expires=Sun, 08-Sep-2024 02:01:08 GMT

CONSENT
CONSENT=PENDING+701;
Path=/;
Domain=google.com;
Secure;
Max-Age=63071999;
Expires=Fri, 08-Aug-2025 09:42:50 GMT
```

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments. Try to learn the markup and why your question had to be fixed by ewokx. Avoid putting each sentence into a new paragraph.

Comment: Need more debugging.  What do the complete headers of the initial response look like? Is the CookieManager accepting all cookies that are being presented (ie, are you getting an `OnNewCookie` event for every one? Cookies that can't be parsed are not given to the event)? What do the complete headers of the final request look like? Is the CookieManager not sending all cookies back to the server?